How do I create folder from file name and move files into folder and change foldername
I'm trying to create an automation in a batchfile to create folders from filenames and move the files with a different filename to this new created folders.
I've got a bunch of Excel files and the first few tokens are the same in these files.
So for the created folders i need to remove the first 12 tokens and the extensions.
Only managed to adjust the filenames, but the folders need the same name without the extensions .xlsx.
I saw this code and tried to adjust it.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\Bureaublad\1"
set "DestDir=C:\Bureaublad\1"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "%SourceDir%\Kamekllofis*.*" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol= tokens=1 delims=." %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%DestDir%\%%B" 2>nul
        set "FileName=%%A"
        call move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%B\%%FileName:~12%%"
    )
)

Tried this
md "%DestDir%\%%B:~12%%" 2>nul
I just need the first characters from the filename removed and the extension .xlsx

You know how to create the correct file names. Why don't you use the same method to create the correct foldernames? By the way - you don't need the second for loop when you use modifiers (see for /?)
...
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A-D-H "*.pdf" 2^>nul') do (
    set "FName=%%~nA"
    call md "%DestDir%\%%FName:~12%%" 2>nul
    call move /Y "%SourceDir%\%%A" "%DestDir%\%%FName:~12%%\%%FName:~12%%%%~xA"
)


Thank you! This works. Only needed to change was the .pdf extension.

%%~xA is the extension. (.pdf here, because you already filtered for pdf files and  so no other extensions are processed)
